# Adding PHP alternate table row colours to existing HTML table

Tags: php, html-table

I have a Table already written in PHP that echos out data called from the database like so:

```
<TABLE cellSpacing=1 cellPadding=2 align=center bgColor=#aaaaaa border=0 width="100%" class="logintbl">
             <TR>
              <TD bgColor=whitesmoke colSpan=0><B>Pages</B></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table align="center" cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=2 border="0" width="100%">
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center" valign="bottom">&nbsp;<font color="#4d71a1"><b>Page Name</b></font>&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php while ($row = mssql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
                        <tr bgcolor="#eeeeee">

                            <td align="center"><?php echo $row["PageURL"]; ?></td>
                            <td align="center">
                            <a href="PageUpdate.php?id=<?php echo $row["PageID"]; ?>"><img src="images/0013-pen.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="" border="0"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            </td>

                        </tr>
                <?php } ?>
                        <tr><td colspan="7">&nbsp;</td></tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="7" align="center">
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

I have been trying to alternate the colours of the rows, using a snippet of PHP and after some research implemented this:

```
<tr bgcolor="<?php echo ($clrCounter++ % 2 == 0 ? '#000000' : '#ffffff'); ?>">
```

It doesn't seem to work correctly, so I feel I am going wrong somewhere, I know there is longer ways to implement this that I could implement. I was just hoping for something simple. Am I wasting effort trying to implement it this way?

I integrated it as follows:

```
 <TABLE cellSpacing=1 cellPadding=2 align=center bgColor=#aaaaaa border=0 width="100%" class="logintbl">
            <TR>
              <td bgColor=whitesmoke colSpan=0><B>Pages</B></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table align="center" cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=2 border="0" width="100%">
                        <tr bgcolor="#3A7525">
                            <td align="center" valign="bottom">&nbsp;<font color="#4d71a1"><b>Page Name</b></font>&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php while ($row = mssql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>

                        <tr bgcolor="<?php echo ($clrCounter++ % 2 == 0 ? '#C2C2C2' : '#ffffff'); ?>">

                            <td align="center"><?php echo $row["PageURL"]; ?></td>
                            <td align="center">
                            <a href="PageUpdate.php?id=<?php echo $row["PageID"]; ?>"><img src="images/0013-pen.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="" border="0"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            </td>

                        </tr>
                <?php } ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="7" align="center">
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

It sort of works, but for some reason the very first entry is blue? When I've specified white and grey.

Comment: The code is 'good'. Can you show us you integrated it to the code above ?

Comment: Don't use inline properties to define styles; go for CSS instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the following when looping through the results returned from your db:

```
<?php

// Define row colors
$color1 = "#FFFFFF";
$color2 = "#F4F9FF";

// Set row counter
$row_count = 0;

while ($row = mssql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $row_color = ($row_count % 2) ? $color1 : $color2;
?>
    <tr bgcolor="<?php echo $row_color; ?>">
        <td align="center"><?php echo $row["PageURL"]; ?></td>
        <td align="center">
            <a href="PageUpdate.php?id=<?php echo $row["PageID"]; ?>"><img src="images/0013-pen.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="" border="0"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php

    $row_count++;

}

?>
```

Alternatively, you could replace the bgcolor tags and assign a CSS class to each row.

Answer (score 4):

Use the CSS selector `:nth-of-type( )`.

By putting different styles for both the `:nth-of-type(even)` and `:nth-of-type(odd)` the browser does the alternating styling for you, so you won't have to worry about it.

See the [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-of-type.asp) entry on this.

Comment: I would like to do it this way, but after reading this article on W3C, because my rows are all generated by the number of entries in the database, they all seem to see themselves as even, therefore are all the same colour?

Comment: Generating the table from a database shouldn't affect the CSS, because your server delivers an HTML web page and your browser marks it up, independent of what your server did to it.

Comment: also not supported in IE8, so check your usage shares.. you may want to do it another way.

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
<tr <?php if($i%2){?>bgcolor="#eeeeee"<?php } else{ ?>bgcolor="red" <?php } $i++; ?>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Bas van den Heuvel for the great answer using CSS.  If you encountered extra line spacing like I did, and want to remove it, use the following example code.  This will make the alternating color lines be tighter together.  (I used light grey and white)

```
p:nth-of-type(odd)
{
background:#e2e2e2;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}
p:nth-of-type(even)
{
background:#ffffff;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}
```